# Shading Exported .OBJ Model in Element 3D

Tags: modeling, shaders, obj

I am sure there is a simple answer to this question as I am just missing a step so kindly ask you to point out what that step is.

I've just created a simple TV model in blender, making sure to separate all its parts and putting them into different collections (Not sure if this is the right way to achieve the desired result) however, when I import the model into Element 3D and apply a shading colour to it, I cannot colour all the elements of the model separately. What do I need to do to be able to?

[image]
[image]

Comment: As I understand [their documentation](https://www.videocopilot.net/docs/element/importing_3d_objects_into_element_3d/exporting_3d_objects_for_element_3d/), you just have to assign a different material to each part of the object in Blender... Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and sending me this link! I followed the instructions and all worked as I needed. Much obliged.